# Unable to call PHP function in HTML file, tried using the same code in different code its working fine but not here

Tags: php, html, sql

When I press the Login button it refreshes the page and doesn't do anything. I tried entering wrong Server IP just to check the error, but I guess it's not responding to the login button and directly refreshing the page.

Unable to call a PHP function in the HTML file, tried using the same code in a different code and it's working fine there but not here:

```
<title> Database Login </title>
<body>

</head>
<body>
<span>
<div class="heading">

 <h3><img src="http://zicom.com/img/ilayashop-1482233381.jpg" alt="Zicom       Logo" >

  <h1><b>MAaaS Login<b></h1><br>
 </span>
</div>

    <div class='admin'>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                    <p class='main'> Enter your Details </p>
            <p> Enter User Name <input type="text" name="name"     id="userInput"></p>


    <p> Enter password <input type="password" name="pass" id="userInput">     </p>
  <br>
 <input id="login" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">

 </form>
 </div>


<?php

if($_POST){

    $UN = $_POST['name'];
    $PS = $_POST['pass'];

    $scon=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXXXXXX;        Database=Sampledata;","XX","XXXXX");
$query="SELECT [password] FROM [Simcarddata].[dbo].[MasterUser] Where username='$UN'";

  $rs=odbc_exec($scon,$query);
  if (!$rs)
    {
    $msg="SQL statement failed with error:\n";
   $msg.=odbc_error($scon).": ".odbc_errormsg($scon)."\n";
  } else {
$number_of_rows = odbc_num_rows($rs);
$msg="$number_of_rows records found.\n";
}
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{

$field1 =  odbc_result($rs,1);
// print ("$PS and $field1");
if ($PS == $field1){
    print ("TRUE");

     header("Location: /test.php");
}
else {
    print ("Incorrect Username or password");
}

}
odbc_close($scon);
  header("Refresh:2");
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: might be a silly question but this page has the `.php` extension? It could also be down the the badly formed HTML where you have  `<body></head><body>`. Also - you can't use `header` once you hae sent html content

Comment: The html is all over the place - my guess is the badly formed HTML is the root issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I just tidied up the HTML tags a little and used a better method of checking for POST data - but I think the issue was the badly formed HTML was confusing the form

```
<html>
    </head>
        <title> Database Login </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><img src="http://zicom.com/img/ilayashop-1482233381.jpg" alt="Zicom Logo" ></h3>
                <h1><b>MAaaS Login<b></h1>
                <br>
            </div>
        </span>


        <div class='admin'>
            <form method='post'>
                <p class='main'> Enter your Details </p>
                <p>Enter User Name <input type="text" name="name" id="userInput"></p>
                <p>Enter password <input type="password" name="pass" id="userInput"></p>
                <br>
                <input id="login" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>


        <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['name'], $_POST['pass'] ) ){

                $UN = $_POST['name'];
                $PS = $_POST['pass'];

                $scon=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXXXXXX;Database=Sampledata;","XX","XXXXX");
                $query="SELECT [password] FROM [Simcarddata].[dbo].[MasterUser] Where username='$UN'";

                $rs=odbc_exec( $scon, $query );

                if (!$rs) {
                    $msg="SQL statement failed with error:\n";
                    $msg.=odbc_error($scon).": ".odbc_errormsg($scon)."\n";
                } else {
                    $number_of_rows = odbc_num_rows($rs);
                    $msg="$number_of_rows records found.\n";
                }
                while( odbc_fetch_row( $rs ) ) {

                    $field1 =  odbc_result($rs,1);
                    if ($PS == $field1){
                        print ("TRUE");

                        header("Location: /test.php");
                    } else {
                        print ("Incorrect Username or password");
                    }
                }
                odbc_close($scon);
                header("Refresh:2");
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still im facing the same issue, after pressing the login button page refreshes and gets back to login page.

Answer (score -1):

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') use this please instead of if($_POST) or use if(isset($_POST))